# Low benchmark= faulty or slightly faulty cpu?

Tags: cpu, benchmarking

If a phone/computer scores slightly lower on a benchmark than the rest...not drastically but significant enough to be noticed could the cpu be damaged? What I am asking is that if a cpu is damaged will the geekbench/benchmark be drastically worse or can it just result in slightly slower speeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect its unlikely that CPU damage would be the cause this - I'd expect kernel errors or data corruption if the CPU was faulty.  It is much, much more likely to be a firmware issue, or possibly a heat dissipation issue.   Its also possible that its just got different software running in the background.